# How to exclude the drivers/pci directory from compilation during Linux kernel compilation, while still allowing make to find symbols in its .o files?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, compilation, gnu-make

## Problem Description

When switching the project compiler from gcc 9.3 to clang 11, there are a few files in the existing drivers/pci directory that fail to compile with the new compiler. As a workaround, these files were compiled with the original compiler and then copied over. The expectation was that when running make, the contents of this directory, having already been compiled, would not be compiled again. However, the pci directory is still being compiled, leading to continued errors.

### Attempted Solutions

1. Modification of File Timestamps: Attempted to influence the build process using timestamps in the Makefile. Modified the timestamps of all files in the pci directory, compiled with gcc, to a date like the year 2000. Even after these changes, the directory is still being compiled upon re-running the build.
2. Commenting out Directory in Makefile: Commented out the line objm+= /pci in the Makefile within the drivers directory. This resulted in linker errors when other files in the kernel that need to reference symbols in the .o files of the pci directory tried to link.

```bash
Copy code
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: pci_find_bus
>>> referenced by pci.c:40 (kernel/arch/arm64/kernel/pci.c:40)
```

## Seeking Help

Is there a way to prevent the new compiler from compiling the pci directory while also allowing successful linking to symbols in the corresponding .o files of the pci directory during the linking process?

Comment: "*Is there a way to prevent the new compiler from compiling the pci directory*" -- A compiler should only be dealing with individual source files. It's the **make** scripts that control which files are compiled. **Make** should only be compiling a source file if there is no corresponding **.o** file, or if the source file has a more recent timestamp than its **.o** file. What have you done to break these simple rules? BTW are you positive that these two compilers even use the same object format, which is a requisite for what you're doing?

Comment: I've set the *.c *.h files timestamp to the year 2021, and  the timestamp of files generated by gcc  to the year 2022. Don't know why the *.o files still get generated.
Just want to use this trick to avoid those errors for a short time. Clang uses a more strict checking rule. Truly the incompatibility may occur. So I'll minimize the replaced .o files

Comment: The most reasonable way for me is to create a **wrapper script** for the compiler, and specify path to that script in the `CC` variable. In the wrapper script you could scan command line arguments for the presence of "problematic" sources files under `drivers/pci`. If command line contains such files, then call "old compiler" and forward it all the command line arguments. Otherwise call "new compiler" with all that arguments.

Comment: "*I've set the *.c *.h files timestamp ...*" - Instead of just one timestamp, a file IIRC has three (3) timestamps. Which one of the three did you change. Which one does Make use for the comparison?

Comment: The Linux build system doesn't just reply on timestamps when deciding to recompile. If any changes to the CONFIG settings affect an object file, it will be recompiled. If there are changes to the compiler command line, the object files will be recompiled. See the comments at the top of [fixdep.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/basic/fixdep.c) for the details.

Comment: Great thanks to @IanAbbott, this is where the problem lies in.  I've also find [Command change detection](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#command-change-detection) in the kernel documentation website.

Comment: @sawdust The time i've modified is the mtime(modification time). The stat command can show the three timestamps: mtime, atime, ctime

Comment: You could attempt to correct the files that failed to compile with clang 11. They might have already been corrected upstream.